# how can I use shopware event-subscriber properly

Tags: plugins, shopware, subscriber

I've created a custom plugin *SwagStartup* in Shopware, and it works by calling an url like "shopware.project/myDemo".

Then I tried to define/use event subscriber in this plugin, following is the code:

```
<?php
namespace SwagStartup\Subscriber;
use Enlight\Event\SubscriberInterface;

class RoutingSubscriber implements SubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(){
        return ['Enlight_Controller_Action_PreDispatch' => 'onPreDispatch'];
    }
    public function onPreDispatch(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args){
        die('here!');
    }
}
```

And the XML file: Resources/services.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="swag_startup.subscriber.routing_subscriber"
                 class="SwagStartup\Subscriber\RoutingSubscriber">
            <tag name="shopware.event_subscriber"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

When I called the url like before, I expected to see the output from the die() function, cause I thought the event *Enlight_Controller_Action_PreDispatch* should have been caught by the subscriber and the funciton *onPreDispatch()* should have been called - but it was not the case.

What's wrong? Can someone tell me?

Comment: Looks fine on first glance. Did you clear the cache? Is the plugin installed and active?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same in a testplugin and it works fine: https://github.com/mnaczenski/SubscriberTest

It seems that your subscriber is not recognised. Which shopware version do you use?

Comment: Thanks for your effor! My experience is a little bit confusing. The code that I posted did really NOT work. But now it WORKS. I don't know why! I did NOT change anything...

Comment: Maybe you did not clear the cache before?

Answer (score 0):

Late  reply but issue still valid with SW 6.4

What I tried to do (And worked) was

1. remove the class from the subscriber service. Just leave the id
2. moved the <tag above the arguments